# Laravel Raw Query does not recognise alias

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

**What i want:** I have a model and want to fire a raw query. I use a `selectRaw()` for this. Inside the selectRaw I pass the select string with an `as` as alias. When I fire the query I get the desired list including the alias.

**Problem:** But now I want to filter the alias. For this I use where Raw. I would also like to change the pure order. For this I use `whereRaw()` and `orderRaw()`. Unfortunately, I then get an error message:

`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Distance' in...`

My query:

```php
Model::selectRaw('col1,col2,col3,
            (6368 * SQRT(2*(1-cos(RADIANS(lat))))) AS Distance')
            ->whereRaw('Distance <= 3')
            ->orderByRaw('Distance')
            ->take(20)
            ->get();
```

**Question:** Why does it not recognise the alias Distance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Mysql Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html) about aliases.

It simply says, that you can't use alias in where clauses, simply because it is not evaluated when where runs.

> Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined. For example, the following query is illegal:

Instead you can use `HAVING` or eloquent `having` function.

```
Model::selectRaw('
  col1,
  col2,
  col3, 
  (6368 * SQRT(2*(1-cos(RADIANS(lat))))) AS Distance
')
->having('Distance', '<=' '3')
->orderByRaw('Distance')
->take(20)
->get();
```

It should work.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir! With `having` works.  No i got another question.

Comment: I have another question. It sorts the results after the comma incorrectly. Distance desc: `1.5, 2.9 ,2.5 ,2.1` and actually it should be: `1.5, 2.1, 2.5, 2.9`. Do you have any spontaneous advice here?

Comment: does ->orderBy('Distance') not work for that?

Comment: No it won't work. Because it's alias, not column. Try using orderByRaw and place that calculation inside it, it will work, but can be expensive calculation. You should consider writing subquery for it and get that column from there. That way you can filter with where and dont do same calculation multiple times

Comment: Thank You for explaination. I learn something today ;-)

Comment: No problem, let me know if you have problem writing subquery

Comment: @andylondon Sorry my mistake. I got: `9.4890594482422E-5, 2.0190808251783`And i thought that 9.4890594482422E-5 is bigger as `2.0190808251783` But it is smaller ... Thank you for your question.